# How to achieve magento product media image uploaded in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, php, adminhtml, forms, media

Is it possible to get the same media image uploader which is in the product image tab in my custom module. Or any idea for uploading multiple images in adminhtml form of magento. I will like to achieve something like the below image. Can anyone please help me on doing this.[image]

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722090/how-to-upload-images-in-custom-module-like-in-add-product-in-admin-of-magento or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565142/magento-custom-module-which-uploads-multiple-images

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will look into this and i will let you know about this.